# How to make LEFT JOIN in Lambda LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How to make this expression as LEFT JOIN

```
var query = order.Items.Join(productNonCriticalityList,
    i => i.ProductID,
    p => p.ProductID,
    (i, p) => i);
```

Comment: Please note it is the alpha expressions

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 38, accepted):

And this is the more complicated way using lambda expressions to write it:

```
order.Items
   .GroupJoin (
      productNonCriticalityList, 
      i => i.ProductID, 
      p => p.ProductID, 
      (i, g) => 
         new  
         {
            i = i, 
            g = g
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp => temp.g.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
      (temp, p) => 
         new  
         {
            i = temp.i, 
            p = p
         }
   )
```

Comment: I have error in DefaultIfEmpty() function says doesnt contains this function, I understand I have to create in the dto right?

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend switching to `from` syntax and you can use the `into` keyword.

It does the same thing as the method syntax and is far more readable (IMO).

```
(from l1 in myFirstDataSet
join l2 in mySecondDataSet on l1.<join_val> equals l2.<join_val> into leftJ
from lj in leftJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
where <your_where_clause>
select <something>).ToList();
```

Comment: `from...join...into` is simply a `GroupJoin` in method syntax.  It's not *required* to use query syntax.

Comment: @Sergey The two different style of expressions do the same thing. There's no need to favor one over the other. For left joins this is far more readable imo.

Comment: Yes, this is clear for me even VS can convert it from one style to another, but the problem is that I don't have VS now :(

Comment: Could you please provide an example with methods styles?

Comment: @Sergey Magnus provided an example in another post and also noted it's "more complicated". For the sake of the next person that had to read it I'd still recommend sticking with the "from" syntax :D Again, ***they are the same thing***.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've upvoted the answer

Comment: it is not lambda